# Mobile site — scale it to full width

Tags: html, css, mobile

There is a site with fixed width 1280px.

How can I tell a smartphone to scale this site to full width?
At least initially, after page loading.

For now I use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1280, initial-scale=1">
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
Is there any 100% working solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

initial-scale=1 indicate that it will show the actual size of the webpage.
Just cut this parameter out.

Comment: This helped. Thank you for explaination!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a site with a fixed width, then it should help

`<meta name="viewport" content='width=1280' />`

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with this as well (even with the meta tag and checking all widths) and I could not figure out how to resolve it until I started using a css reset. Have you tried this? This is the one I am using to reset the browser's CSS prior to implementing your own code. http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/